# What does different arguments of model.sumary() in keras python mean?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

When I write `model.summary()` I get something like

[image]

How can I get "connected to" argument? Also, can someone tell me the meaning of `None` in output shape argument?

Answer (score 0):

`None` means that the number of samples that you feed into your network is not yet defined. This in general is a hyperparameter that you choose before training and is independent of your models architecture.

`model.summary()` is documented [here](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/)

You might want to look into `model.get_weights()` or `model.get_config()` (which are methods though).

Useful attributes of class `Model` are (per Keras documentation):

- `model.layers`: flattened list of the layers comprising the model graph
- `model.inputs`: list of input tensors
- `model.outputs`: list of output tensors